# data structure used to store file on Unix system

Tags: unix, data-structures

I just made a simple text editor using inbuilt opening, writing, overwriting file.I used python installed with tkinter. But, I also want to extend the text editor to add some new features like search, replace etc efficiently. In order to make it efficient, **I need to know data structure that Unix uses to store data in file and to calculating the time complexity for search.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A text file is stored as a stream of bytes. Depending on the encoding used (ASCII, UTF-8, Unicode, etc.), it can be a fixed value of one or more bytes per character, or in the case of UTF-8 and some other encodings, a varying number of bytes per character.

The best search algorithms have a worst case complexity of O(n + m), where n is the length of the string you're searching for, and m is the length of the string you're searching in. A good example is the [Boyer-Moore search algorithm](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/04/17/computer-algorithms-boyer-moore-string-search-and-matching/). If the file you're working with is larger than will fit in memory, then you have to worry about buffering and such, which is an added complication, but doesn't impact the efficiency of the search. You'll have to be creative about buffering the input so that you don't miss a string that crosses input buffer boundaries.